# '/' character is not coming through query string in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on Angular 2 application in that I have created a route which accepts a encrypted email id through query string parameter.
for ex. encrypted text is NSDds3455rwlk/Dfd237hhSFSDFD= 
then only NSDds3455rwlk string is returned by query string but I want full encrypted string.

Route config in app component

```
@RouteConfig([
 {path: '/reset-password/:un', name: 'ResetPassword', component: ResetPasswordComponent}
])
```

Comment: Can you paste your route code here?

Comment: can you post some of your `ResetPasswordComponent` code? how do you get the data from query params?

Comment: I get value from query string by this code
var un=this.params.get('un');

params is the variable of type RouteParams

Comment: Do you just paste the encrypted text in the address bar, or is it coming from inside the application?

Answer (score 0):

When you attach parameters to your address bar, they need to be URL encoded. Otherwise you might get unexpected results. In your case, the slash in the text is interpreted as a part of the route.

Javascript has built-in functions for encoding and decoding URI components that you can use. `encodeURIComponent("NSDds3455rwlk/Dfd237hhSFSDFD=")` will return `NSDds3455rwlk%2FDfd237hhSFSDFD%3D`, which is a string that is safe to use as a parameter in your route.

On the other side of things, in your `ResetPasswordComponent` code, you should get the parameter value using

```
var un = decodeURIComponent(this.params.get('un'));
```

So you'll have the original string as your parameter.

Answer (score -2):

modify your code with help of below code

```
  /**
 * @Route("/{reset-password}/:un", name="ResetPassword", requirements={"ResetPasswordComponent"=".+"})
 */
```

[More details here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)

Comment: How is this related to Angular 2?

Comment: Does this code for Angular 2?, because the details link shows that it is for Angular 1.x